# AlertDialog setCustomTitle styling to match standard AlertDialog title

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, custom-titlebar

I'm working on an Android app and I have an AlertDialog subclass.  I would like to put 2 ImageButtons on the right side of the title area of the dialog (similar to an the ActionBar in an Activity).  I'm using setCustomTitle() to do this, which replaces the title area with a custom view of my own creation.  This works fine, but the styling of my custom title area is not the same as the standard title styling (height, color, separator, etc).

My question is: **with the understanding that styling varies by OS version and manufacturer**, how can I style my custom title in the dialog so that it will match the standard title styling for other AlertDialogs?

Here is an image of anAlertDialog with standard styling (this is from ICS, but I want to be able to match any variant -- not this particular style) 
[image]

And here is an image of an AlertDialog with custom title and buttons (note how the title height and color don't match the standard dialog)
[image]

EDIT: I can't just add the ImageButtons to the standard title view, because I don't have access to it.  **If you know of a (reliable, non-hack) method for me to add buttons to the standard title area, I would accept that as well.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that there is new interest in this question, let me elaborate about how I "solved" this.

First, I use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) in my app. This is not necessary, I suppose, though it helps a lot because the styles and themes defined in the ABS project allow me to mimic the Holo theme on pre-ICS devices, which provides a consistent experience in the app.

Second, my "dialog" is no longer a dialog -- it's an activity themed as a dialog. This makes manipulation of the view hierarchy simpler, because I have complete control. So adding buttons to the title area is now trivial.

Here are the screenshots (2.2 device and 4.1 emulator). Note that the only significant styling difference is the EditText, which I have chosen not to address.

[image: 2.2 device]
[image: 4.1 emulator]

Here is my onCreate in my dialog activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tag);
    setTitle(R.string.tag_dialog_title);

    View sherlockTitle = findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    if (sherlockTitle != null) {
        sherlockTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    View sherlockDivider = findViewById(R.id.abs__titleDivider);
    if (sherlockDivider != null) {
        sherlockDivider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // setup custom title area
    final View titleArea = findViewById(R.id.dialog_custom_title_area);
    if (titleArea != null) {
        titleArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        TextView titleView = (TextView) titleArea.findViewById(R.id.custom_title);
        if (titleView != null) {
            titleView.setText(R.string.tag_dialog_title);
        }

        ImageButton cancelBtn = (ImageButton) titleArea.findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
        cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        cancelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        ImageButton okBtn = (ImageButton) titleArea.findViewById(R.id.ok_btn);
        okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do stuff here
                finish();
            }
        });
        okBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

And here is the relevant layout for the activity:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_custom_title_area"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingRight="10dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/custom_title" style="?android:attr/windowTitleStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/abs__alert_dialog_title_height"
                android:paddingLeft="16dip"
                android:paddingRight="16dip"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ok_btn"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="@dimen/abs__action_button_min_width"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/abs__alert_dialog_title_height"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
                android:background="@drawable/abs__item_background_holo_dark"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription="@string/acc_done"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/cancel_btn"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="@dimen/abs__action_button_min_width"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/abs__alert_dialog_title_height"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
                android:background="@drawable/abs__item_background_holo_dark"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:contentDescription="@string/acc_cancel"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/dialog_title_divider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="@color/abs__holo_blue_light" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_suggestions_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <!-- this is where the main dialog area is laid out -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, in my AndroidManifext.xml, here is how I define my TagActivity:

```
<activity 
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home" 
    android:name=".activity.TagActivity" 
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Dialog"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, maybe it is not the super perfect solution and maybe it is a bad solution, but I tried this on android 2.3.7 and android 4.1.2:

***`2.3.7 (real device)`***

[image: 2.3.7 (real device)]

***`4.1.2 (emulator)`***

[image: 4.1.2 (emulator)]

---

We start by creating a dialog Title style to make sure we have some space for our icons:

***`res/values/dialogstyles.xml`***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyOwnDialogTitle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyOwnDialogTitle">
        <!--  we need to make sure our images fit -->
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">100dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

***`res/values-v11/dialogstyles.xml`***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="Dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MyOwnDialogTitle</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Then we create our DialogFragment with two tricks:

- set the style in the `onCreate`:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.Dialog);
  }
  ```
- override `onCreateView` and add our layout (of buttons) to the Dialog (see comments)

  ```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      //we need the view to remove the tree observer (that's why it is final)
      final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom, container);
      getDialog().setTitle("Shush Dialog");
      //register a layout listener to add our buttons
      view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

          @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
          @SuppressLint("NewApi")
          @Override
          public void onGlobalLayout() {
              //inflate our buttons
              View menu = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.layout_mymenu, null);
              //get the root view of the Dialog (I am pretty sure this is the weakest link)
              FrameLayout fl = ((FrameLayout) getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView());
              //get the height of the root view (to estimate the height of the title) 
              int height = fl.getHeight() - fl.getPaddingTop() - fl.getPaddingBottom();
              //to estimate the height of the title, we subtract our view's height
              //we are sure we have the heights btw because layout is done
              height = height - view.getHeight();
              //prepare the layout params for our view (this includes setting its width)
              //setting the height is not necessary if we ensure it is small
              //we could even add some padding but anyway!
              FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height);
              params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
              //add the view and we are done
              fl.addView(menu, params);
              if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                  view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
              else
                  view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
          }
      });
      return view;
  }
  ```

Answer (score -2):

Alright if it just images, then you just have ensure that everything that you create in xml is scaled by density pixels or DP for short. Most simple coding that sets paint are usually set by pixels as well and may need a manual coding version to density pixels.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I'm looking for.  I've added some image links for clarity.

Comment: I hope this is answers your question.

Comment: No, I think you're still misunderstanding the problem.  (See my latest edit.)  The title area of the dialog is not accessible to me by ID, so I can't just add my buttons to it.  I have to use setCustomTitle(View view), which **replaces** the existing title area.

Comment: I believe that is just wrap content for the over-all layout with a few variation on scaling for the bottom view.